# Nginx: How to log the number of bytes sent over a websocket?

Tags: nginx, websocket

I am using nginx as a websocket reverse-proxy. I would like to log the number of bytes sent (and ideally also received) over a websocket. If I use `$body_bytes_sent` in `log_format`, the entry in the access_log is always 0. As far as I can tell, a lot of data went through the websocket, so clearly `$body_bytes_sent` does not include data sent over a websocket.

I tried to use `$bytes_sent`, but it's just one or two hundred bytes (no matter how much data is sent over the websocket), which is clearly just the HTTP headers. I went through the list of available nginx variables, but I coulnd't find anything for me...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

The problem was that I was using an old version of nginx. With the latest one (1.14.0), `$body_bytes_sent` does log the amount of bytes sent over the websocket.